# Convert xml with namespaces to json in java

Tags: java, json, xml, namespaces, converters

I'm trying to convert xml to json using java and then convert the json back to xml after modifying which should give the same xml. The xml attributes have namespaces.

My sample xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:testplan xmlns:ns2="http://jazz.net/xmlns/alm/qm/v0.1/" xmlns:ns1="http://schema.ibm.com/vega/2008/" xmlns:ns3="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:ns4="http://jazz.net/xmlns/prod/jazz/process/0.6/" xmlns:ns5="http://jazz.net/xmlns/alm/v0.1/" xmlns:ns6="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:ns7="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:ns8="http://jazz.net/xmlns/alm/qm/v0.1/testscript/v0.1/" xmlns:ns9="http://jazz.net/xmlns/alm/qm/v0.1/executionworkitem/v0.1" xmlns:ns10="http://open-services.net/ns/core#" xmlns:ns11="http://open-services.net/ns/qm#" xmlns:ns12="http://jazz.net/xmlns/prod/jazz/rqm/process/1.0/" xmlns:ns13="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" xmlns:ns14="http://jazz.net/xmlns/alm/qm/qmadapter/v0.1" xmlns:ns15="http://jazz.net/xmlns/alm/qm/qmadapter/task/v0.1" xmlns:ns16="http://jazz.net/xmlns/alm/qm/v0.1/executionresult/v0.1" xmlns:ns17="http://jazz.net/xmlns/alm/qm/v0.1/catalog/v0.1" xmlns:ns18="http://jazz.net/xmlns/alm/qm/v0.1/tsl/v0.1/" xmlns:ns20="http://jazz.net/xmlns/alm/qm/styleinfo/v0.1/" xmlns:ns21="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<ns2:projectArea href="https://testserver:9080/qm/resource/itemOid/com.ibm.team.process.ProjectArea/_xv6jsJceEeimRT_G_Q" alias="projectArea"/>
<ns3:identifier>https://testserver:9080/qm/service/com.ibm.rqm.integration.service.IIntegrationService/resources/projectArea/testplan/urn:com.ibm.rqm:testplan:70?revision=294</ns3:identifier>
<ns2:stylesheet href="https://testserver:9080/qm/service/com.ibm.rqm.integration.service.IIntegrationService/resources/projectArea/testplan/urn:com.ibm.rqm:testplan:70?stylesheet=true"/>
<ns2:snapshot>
<ns3:title>testplan_70_&lt;Reason&gt;_&lt;Version&gt;_on_16 Apr 2019 05:50</ns3:title>
<ns5:updated>2019-04-16T12:20:01.644Z</ns5:updated>
<ns2:revision>294</ns2:revision>
</ns2:snapshot>
<ns2:webId>70</ns2:webId>
<ns3:title>Demo test plan 06</ns3:title>
<ns3:description/>
<ns2:creationDate>2019-01-22T10:36:40.289Z</ns2:creationDate>
<ns5:updated>2019-04-16T12:20:01.644Z</ns5:updated>
<ns5:state ns7:resource="https://testserver:9080/qm/service/com.ibm.rqm.integration.service.IIntegrationService/process-info/_xv6jsJceEeRT_G_Q/workflowstate/com.ibm.rqm.process.testplan.workflow/com.ibm.rqm.planning.common.underreview">com.ibm.rqm.planning.common.underreview</ns5:state>
<ns3:creator ns7:resource="https://testserver:9080/jts/resource/itemName/com.ibm.team.repository.Contributor/ABB">abc</ns3:creator>
<ns5:owner>unassigned</ns5:owner>
<ns2:priority ns7:resource="https://testserver:9080/qm/service/com.ibm.rqm.integration.service.IIntegrationService/process-info/_xv6jsJceEeimbPqQ/priority/literal.priority.101">literal.priority.101</ns2:priority>
<ns2:locked>false</ns2:locked>
<ns2:component href="https://testserver:9080/qm/service/com.ibm.rqm.integration.service.IIntegrationService/resources/projectArea/component/_yzQ3EZcmbPqnRT_G_Q"/>
</ns2:testplan>
```

Could someone please help me to convert preciously using java.

I have tried converting using org.json.XML, But it was not giving proper json with jsonobject keys/values having namespaces.

Code I have tried and not giving response:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject("xml");
```

I expect a convertion way which gives Json with proper format and json objects having namespaces,and If I covert this json it should give initial xml
Please help me.

Comment: I mean, there is no such thing as namespaces in JSON, so...

Comment: There is no such thing as namesapce in json. But if we convert a xml to json..the json object can have namespace.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. You should provide examples. But when something doesn't have namespaces to begin with, there is no magical circumstances that will make it somehow that it now has namespaces. JSON doesn't have namespaces. So, nothing will make it so that it has namespaces.

Comment: Yeah I know,json wont have namespaces. But jsonObject or keys can be namspaces right. I have given the xml above and the xml has namespace. I need to convert this xml to json and modify certain values from the json and convert it back.So when i convert it back to xml,I need the namespaces back properly inorder for it to be a valid json

Comment: Namespaces are essentially part of the elements' names: they are always the same. Don't put namespaces in the JSON and just use names that are unique enough that they don't need to be separated in namespaces. Then when converting it back to XML, put the namespaces back. No library will do such a conversion for you, first convert from XML to object then from object to JSON, and the other way around.

Comment: Conversion is because I need the xml back with few modifications to use as request body for a post request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the XmlMapper from jackson (com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper)

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = xmlMapper.readTree(string.getBytes());
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String value = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
```

edit: Dependencies I've used

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the quick response. Could you please tel me what all dependencies needed ?

Comment: Should be "Jackson Dataformat XML" Version 2.9.0 (or higher?)
edit: added Dependency to Answer.

Comment: I have added the dependency you have suggested. But I'm getting a error now . Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.stax2.io.Stax2ByteArraySource  on this line JsonNode jsonNode = xmlMapper.readTree(string.getBytes());

Comment: From where is your XmlMapper imported?
Added another dependency.

Comment: @Ajith, You need "stax2-api" jar file. If you have a Maven project it downloads additional jar files. My project was not Maven and I had imported only these 2 jar files(jackson-databind and jackson-dataformat-xml) as suggested and got the same error. After creating a Maven project and trying adding dependencies, I have seen the other jar files. stax2-api-3.1.4.jar is one of them, probably you will need the other jars as well.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old but I would like to share my answer about the same task that I did recently!
The requirement is:
Having this xml:

```
<ns2:testplan>
 <ns2:snapshot>
    <ns2:revision>294</ns2:revision>
 </ns2:snapshot>
 <ns2:webId>70</ns2:webId>
 <ns2:title>Demo test plan 06</ns2:title>
</ns2:testplan>
```

We would like to convert it to:

```
{
  "ns2:testplan": {
    "ns2:snapshot": {
      "ns2:revision": 294
    },
    "ns2:title": "Demo test plan 06",
    "ns2:webId": 70
  }
}
```

Note that with the accepted response the root tag `<ns2:testplan>` and the namespace prefix are not included in the JSON.
To configure `XmlMapper` to keep the namespace and add the root tag, proceed like this:

```
var module = new SimpleModule().addDeserializer(JsonNode.class, new JsonNodeDeserializer() {
        @Override
        public JsonNode deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            return ctxt.getNodeFactory()
                    .objectNode()
                    .set("ns2:testplan", super.deserialize(p, ctxt)); // this config adds the root tag
        }
    });

XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = new WstxInputFactory();
xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, false); // this one keeps the namespace prefix
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(new XmlFactory(xmlInputFactory, new WstxOutputFactory()));
xmlMapper.registerModule(module);
```

Then use the code of the accepted answer to convert the XML to JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Get a `JSONObject` and convert it to JSON string:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject("xml");
String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();
```

If you want to pretty-print the string, use `toString(int)` which takes number of spaces as an argument.

```
String prettyPrintedJson = jsonObject.toString(4);
```

Comment: Not solving question topic...